# Control docking not working correctly in Visual C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, docking

Here's what I did:

1. Place a TextBox control
2. Set its Multiline property to True, and its Dock property to Fill
3. Place a Button control (also works with a ToolStrip, which is docked at the top by default, and many other controls)
4. Set its Dock property to Top

Here's the problem I'm having:

[image: The button is overlapping the text field.]

Shouldn't the top of the text field be at the bottom of the button? Why is the button overlapping it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong sequence, when you place your `TextBox` first and set its `Dock` Property to `Fill` it will take up the `Form's` complete client area, then when you place your `Button` it overlays your `TextBox`. Try adding the `Button` first setting its `Dock` Property to `Top`, then add your `TextBox` setting its `Dock` Property to `Fill`. It should then work as expected.

---

On further investigation it looks like it has to do with the z-order, if you right click your button and select send to back it should cause the textbox to correct itself.

Comment: Okay, but how would I change that once I've already placed the controls without having to delete them? It's just that if later I decide to add a new docked control, I don't want to have to delete it and make it again. Is there any quicker way to do that, barring editing the .Designer.cs?

Comment: It looks like it has to do with the z-order, if you right click your button and select send to back it should cause the textbox to correct itself.